# Generate array with 3 gaussian distributions MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, gaussian

I need help! My purpose is to develop in MATLAB a routine that, starting from a series of actions (modeled by a label, a mean value and a variance), is able to generate an array of activity. I explain better with my code:

```
action_awake_in_bed = [1 5*60 1*60];
action_out_of_bed = [3 30 10];
action_out_bedroom = [2 2*60 15];
ACTIVITY_WAKE = {'action_awake_in_bed','action_out_of_bed','action_out_bedroom'};
```

The first element of action array is a label (a posture label), the second element is the length of the action (in seconds), the third element the variance.

I need as output the array `ACTIVITY_WAKE`....

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear: are you expecting an array with labels `[1 2 3]` with the amount of each label is distributed with a different mean and variance?

Comment: Yes, I expect an array in output with a sequence of labels ordered by the action and distributed with the different mean and variance that I have indicate as parameter in the array of actions..For example the array "ACTIVITY_WAKE' could start with 1111111111 (for 300 time +/-60), after 3333333 (30 times +/-10) and finally 2222222 (120 times +-15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a struct to store the meta-parameters

```
action.awake_in_bed   = [1 5*60 1*60];
action.out_of_bad     = [3 30 10];
action.out_of_bedroom = [2 2*60 15];
ACTIVITY = {'awake_in_bed','out_of_bad','out_of_bedroom'};
```

After these pre-definitions, we can sample an activity vector

```
ACTIVITY_WAKE = cell(1,numel(ACTIVITY)); 
for ii = 1:numel( ACTIVITY ) %// foreach activity
    cp = action.(ACTIVITY{ii}); %// get parameters of current activity
    n = round( cp(2) + sqrt(cp(3))*randn() ); %// get the number of samples
    ACTIVITY_WAKE{ii} = repmat( cp(1), 1, n );
end
ACTIVITY_WAKE = [ ACTIVITY_WAKE{:} ];
```

To get the number of samples I use the [following](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/random-numbers-with-specific-mean-and-variance.html) recipe to sample from a normal distribution with `mean~=0` and `std~=1`.

Comment: Are you sure about the formula to obtain n? Because I obtain always values near the mean value, with little variance...